# Warning: Passing arguments make pointer from integer

Tags: c

```
    struct config_struct {
    int port; };

 void read_int_from_config_line(char* config_line, int* val) {
    char prm_name[MAX_VARIABLE_LEN];
    sscanf(config_line, "%s %d\n", prm_name, val); }

void read_config_file(char* config_filename, struct config_struct config) {
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];

    fp= fopen("settings.conf", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    printf("Config file does not exist, Creating one.../n");
    {
        fp = fopen("settings.conf", "w+");
        fputs("NAME:Root\nIP:192.168.0.1\nPORT:20\nLOGFILE:\n", fp);
    }
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s", buffer) != EOF)
    {
        fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, fp);
        if (buffer[0] == '#') {
            continue;
        }
        if(!strcmp(buffer,"PORT:")) {
            read_int_from_config_line(buffer ,config.port);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
```

I got the warning `passing argument 2 of ‘read_int_from_config_line’ makes pointer from integer without a cast`
read_int_from_config_line(buffer ,config.port);

May I know how do I solve this? I may be an complete idiot to C as I just started 4weeks ago. Some help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `read_int_from_config_line(buffer ,&config.port);`

Comment: problem is: you'll have a hard time reading parameter name with your routine because it reads a local parameter that it doesn't return afterwards.

Comment: To expand a bit on the useful but terse comment above: the second argument of `read_int_from_config_line()` is a pointer to `int`. You are passing `config.port`, which is an `int`. So the compiler complains that you are making a pointer from an integer. You need to pass the *address* of `config.port`.

Answer (score 0):

I need to see how you are calling that function. What i can say is that you are trying to print where the pointer is pointing and not the value. To print the value *val .